# I disabled watchdogs but I still get a WDT timeout

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, esp32, watchdog

I'm trying to disable all watchdogs from one core. I'm using an ESP32 MH-ET LIVE on Arduino IDE. I'm trying the following in setup() and making a new max priority task (with IRAM_ATTR) on cpu0:

```
rtc_wdt_protect_off(); 
rtc_wdt_disable();
disableCore0WDT();
disableLoopWDT();
```

However, when I try and use:

```
 static portMUX_TYPE my_mutex; (below #includes)
 vPortCPUInitializeMutex(&my_mutex); (in setup)
 portENTER_CRITICAL(&my_mutex); (in task)
```

I get still get `Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU0)`.

I'm looking to disable the watchdog so I can stay in portENTER_CRITICAL indefinitely on one core because I'm successfully bitbanging at decently fast speeds, but the FreeRTOS ticks and background stuff ends up throwing random 1-2us delays that wreck it. I realize this sacrifices the ability to use timers and extra tasks on that core, but I can accept that. I can't use interrupts in this case, as ESP32 takes +2us to handle the interrupt.

Here's some minimal example code, if I uncomment the portENTER/portEXIT code, it errors out.

```
#include "soc/rtc_wdt.h"
#include "esp_int_wdt.h"
#include "esp_task_wdt.h"

static portMUX_TYPE my_mutex;

IRAM_ATTR void setup() {
  rtc_wdt_protect_off();
  rtc_wdt_disable();
  disableCore0WDT();
  disableLoopWDT();
  vPortCPUInitializeMutex(&my_mutex);
  
  Serial.begin(115200);

  TaskHandle_t Task2;
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
      Select,   /* Function to implement the task */
      "Select", /* Name of the task */
      10000,           /* Stack size in words */
      NULL,            /* Task input parameter */
      configMAX_PRIORITIES,               /* Priority of the task */
      &Task2,          /* Task handle. */
      0);              /* Core where the task should run */

}

IRAM_ATTR void Select( void * parameter) {
  unsigned long sincePrint = millis();
  
  portENTER_CRITICAL(&my_mutex);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    digitalWrite(22, 1);
    digitalWrite(22, 0);
    esp_task_wdt_reset();
  } 
  portEXIT_CRITICAL(&my_mutex);

  Serial.print(millis() - sincePrint);

  vTaskDelete(0);
}

void loop() {
  vTaskDelay(portMAX_DELAY);
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: @voxobscuro "Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU0)"

Comment: The error you're getting isn't a watchdog timeout on the task, it's a watchdog timeout on the interrupt. If you look at the backtrace of the two cores, which is printed when that core panic happens, you'll see that one of the cores is waiting on some interrupt driven code -- perhaps it's the serial driver. That trace is what I think will be helpful in identifying what routines need to be shut off or fed.

Comment: For fast, timing critical applications it's often worth shedding the overhead of digitalWrite for register manipulation. In this case esp32 has a REG_WRITE defined, which google has a reasonable result set for. You can also `#undef CONFIG_AUTOSTART_ARDUINO` and provide your own void app_main() to avoid the main arduino loop altogether. You're running a tight ship when µs are important, and every little bit helps.

Comment: @voxobscuro Here is the full error I get: https://pastebin.com/raw/jsLMN2jc
Does any of that help? I'm not sure how to go about getting a full function trace out of it. It's panicking on Core 0, which should only be running the task I spawned (from what I know, the main loop and setup run on Core 1 by default). Commenting out the serial line didn't help, but maybe the driver runs in the background?

In my actual code, I'm actually using direct port manipulation, this is just a minimal reproducible example. That's interesting that you can undef the main arduino loop, I may look into that.

Comment: your trace is still encoded, so it's not of any help yet. If you're using the Arduino IDE, https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder or if you're using Platform.io, you can toggle it in the serial monitor. That'll give you a readable stack trace.

Comment: Ah, I see. I went ahead and did that and got this: https://pastebin.com/raw/E4yNT6bz

The line it refers to is just the first digital light in the loop.

Comment: Any other ideas of what it might be @voxobscuro ?

Comment: I got same problem and found out that i had an infinite loop in my code.